# Encrypt and decrypt JSON data in Android

Tags: java, android, json, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt with send the request and get the response from the server in my android application and I used JSON web services but I'm getting RuntimeException. I don't know how to do this.

Here is my Activity code.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   Button btnPost;

    static String key="Dyv6ACIDe2q+OEjztjfNDw==";
    Person person;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
         btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    static String RequestId="3465768789";
    static String strRequestCode="001";
    static String stringChannelId="MobileApp";
    static String strIpAddress = "192.168.1.123";
    static String strStatusFlag="true";
    static String strUserId="test@test.com";
    static String strPassword="password1";
    static String strVendorId="001";
    static String strRequestId="09";
    static String strRequest="CLIENT";


 public static String POST(String url, Person person)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            jsonObject.accumulate("RequestId", strRequestId);
            jsonObject.accumulate("RequestCode", strRequestCode);
            jsonObject.accumulate("ChannelId", stringChannelId);
            jsonObject.accumulate("IPAddress", strIpAddress);
            jsonObject.accumulate("ForceChangeFlag",strStatusFlag);
            jsonObject.accumulate("UserId", strUserId);
            jsonObject.accumulate("Password",strPassword);
            jsonObject.accumulate("Request",strRequest );
            jsonObject.accumulate("VendorId", strVendorId);


            json = jsonObject.toString();


            String reqvalues=AES128Bit.encrypt(jsonObject.toString().toString(),key);

            Log.e("Reqvalues","  = "+reqvalues);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(reqvalues);


            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
         return result;
    }


 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) 
      {
           new  HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://test.window2india.com/cms/json/w2iWS");
      }

    }



private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {

            person = new Person();
            person.setRequestId(strRequestId);
            person.setRequestCode(strRequestCode);
            person.setChannelId(stringChannelId);
            person.setIPAddress(strIpAddress);
            person.setStatusFlag(strStatusFlag);
            person.setUserId(strUserId);
            person.setPassword(strPassword);
            person.setRequest(strRequest);
            person.setVendorId(strVendorId);

            String strPerson=person.toString();


            Log.e("strPerson ", " =" + strPerson);

            return POST(urls[0],person);
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }


 private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }   
}
```

Here is log cat information.

```
12-28 10:21:15.183: I/dalvikvm(417): Could not find method com.anm.cms.core.util.AES128Bit.encrypt, referenced from method com.json_to_server.MainActivity.POST
    12-28 10:21:15.223: W/dalvikvm(417): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5048: Lcom/anm/cms/core/util/AES128Bit;.encrypt (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    12-28 10:21:15.223: D/dalvikvm(417): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0061
    12-28 10:21:15.362: D/dalvikvm(417): VFY: dead code 0x0064-00a0 in Lcom/json_to_server/MainActivity;.POST (Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/json_to_server/Person;)Ljava/lang/String;
    12-28 10:21:15.362: D/dalvikvm(417): VFY: dead code 0x00a2-00a4 in Lcom/json_to_server/MainActivity;.POST (Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/json_to_server/Person;)Ljava/lang/String;
    12-28 10:21:33.963: E/strPerson(417):  =com.json_to_server.Person@40527d08
    12-28 10:21:33.993: W/dalvikvm(417): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.anm.cms.core.util.AES128Bit
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.json_to_server.MainActivity.POST(MainActivity.java:120)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.json_to_server.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:202)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at com.json_to_server.MainActivity$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: Why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: @chrylis I don't understand what you saying?

Comment: Secure Http channel over SSL, this is speaking HTTP over an encrypted channel. This way you focus on your code and the protocol handles the encryption and decryption from within your sever. The way you are describing in your code though only makes sense if you want to make sure the data is not plaintext past your web layer in which case your server shouldn't be reading it.

Comment: Have you copied the jar files to libs folder check once.

Comment: No Not in lib folder , its in Referenced Libraries.

Comment: add to libs. check the name libs not lib.

Comment: This looks like like it could be an issue to do with an obfuscater, such as proguard. You get similar messages when you obfuscate code and don't keep required classes / methods and then try to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Your logcat points out that you haven't kept the required library in your classpath (probably build path can reference to it hence you're not getting a compilation error).

```
12-28 10:21:34.003: E/AndroidRuntime(417): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.anm.cms.core.util.AES128Bit
```

Please ensure you are referencing to the correct libs in your classpath as well.

**EDIT:** You can try to ensure jars are available at runtime by the following process too;

1. Go to **Java Build Path** and **Order and Export** tab
2. Ensure your external jar is 'checked'
3. Move it to the top of the list

[image]

Comment: Yah I have kept the jar files in references libraries like = right clik on project->properties->java build path->Libraries->Add External Jar

Comment: I have to use sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar and third party encryption jar file.

Comment: Try dumping the external jar (containing your AES128Bit) within your project's lib/libs folder too and referencing from there?

Comment: I tried to kept jar files into libs folder but it can not copy over there it shows the message "cannot paste the clipboard content into the selected element"  and also i have tried like this also project->properties->java build path->Libraries->Add External Jar – but it goes only in Ref libraries not in libs folder.

Comment: @tazeenmulani Strange, can you please try `project->clean` and try again? Or else, close your eclipse, go to your workspace directory in windows and copy jars from there.

Comment: I,m trying as say but still getting same error NoClassDefFoundError .

Comment: Can you try finding the classpath in your eclipse; assuming you're using ADT - right click on your class in Package Explorer,  `Run  -> Run Configurations` and check if your jar is listed within the Classpath?

Comment: @PopFibo , I'm not able to see class path in run configuration only seeing project name in Android tab.

Comment: Hmm, I looked at ADT and yes your don't have that option on a normal class: try these things:
1. Ensure the jar (which you want to use) is 'checked' in Java build path window
2. If step 1 doesn't resolve, go to right click your project `Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties`
3. If not, then got to `Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler compliance` - check the version being used there (1.7 or 1.6) and try fiddling with it (if 1.7 then make it 1.6)

Comment: For the 1st point above please ensure the jar (which you want to use) is 'checked' in Java build path window within **Order and Export** tab

Answer (score -2):

Your original JSON string (the one you show in your first snippet) looks to be valid JSON already. You must not encode it. Encoding it is what makes it invalid JSON, transforming every tab into \t, and every new line into \n.

Read the documentation of json_encode carefully.

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: This is not at all a relevant answer to the question.